# Django Operational error on external db connection

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I'm using an `Azure Virtual Machine` with `ubuntu server`.

I `ssh` into the machine and installed a lamp server (and also `phpmyadmin`, so i can view via browser my databases and execute operations). 
My `django` project is running on my `macbook`.

I tried to connect to the `mysql` database installed on the VM in `django` using the method explained both in documentation and other stackoverflow questions, but none of them are working.

Let's say `1.2.3.4` is my VM `IP`.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    # mysql
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DBname',
        'USER': 'rootuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'rootPassword',
        'HOST': '1.2.3.4',
    },
}
```

Output of `python manage.py runserver`:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError:
  (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (timed out)")
```

Do I need to configure the `mysql` database? Isn't `1.2.3.4` the same IP that I need to use for the db connection?

Also when I try to install `mysqlclient` with `pip install mysqlclient` it raises an error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
  in /private/var/folders/st/8qzvdtwx6xsc1w1ffqd2c7br0000gn/T/pip-install-p25gukfh/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: maybe you need to specify port no. also ? proper inbound/outbound traffic rules are set ?

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work, the port was 3306, but i get the same operational error from django

Comment: @Umair what do you mean with "traffic rules"? do i need to configure my router or the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on `mysql` connections, but as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/9225671):

> What is disabled by default is remote `root` access. If you want to enable that, run this SQL [...]

Maybe you can check that first to rule out this kind of misconfig.
Or try a different user that is not `root`.